# Maintaining session after browser is closed

Tags: session, session-state

How does one implement maintaining sessions securely. Suppose just the login page uses SSL. So the user enters his usernamepassword and the http server verifies it is in the database and now what?

Does it set some cookie? If so then what should the cookie be set to so that security is maintained (encrypted, what kind of encryption)? Looking for a low level detailed answer. I hear there are various cookie hijacking concerns. If I only use SSL for the login but thereafter don't use SSL will the cookie be vulnerable?

Then after the browser is closed and the user comes back how does the cookie identify the username. How is this done securely without the cookie being stolen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **definitely** expose your clients to session theft if your connection is not **encrypted at all times**.

HTTP is a stateless protocol, so the only way to fake a stateful interaction is for client and server to send a session identifier with every transaction. If this isn't protected, it can trivially be stolen. Since the session identifier is the *only* authentication token during the open session, this is catastrophic.

The usual way to make a "remember me" feature would be to set a cookie whose lifetime is not limited to the browser's program lifetime (i.e. by setting an explicit expiration date), and storing some unique data in the cookie which you match against some remembering data (including the IP perhaps) in your database. But that does not absolve you from the need to encrypt all communication!

Comment: Ok so suppose I use SSL always. Then what should the cookie data be? Is there some kind of de facto standard solution for this that I coludn't find on the web? So SSL helps solve the problem of an outsider hijacking the cookie. How does one solve the problem of preventing the user from impersonating others.

Comment: @user: Are you talking about the "remember me" feature now, or about the usual password-authenticated login? I'm sure there are loads of tutorials online if you search for "remember me". Basically you would store some unguessable token both in your DB and in the client's cookie, that'd be hard to impersonate.

Comment: Ok I found this site about persistent login cookies http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/ A follow up question. For nonpersistent logins what is the simpler solution to maintain session state until the user closes their browser?

Comment: @user: In PHP you don't have to do anything, `session_start` will entirely take care of everything for you in the non-persistent case.

Comment: Ok but I would like to understand what its doing at a low level.

Comment: @user: Hey, why no more answer accepted? :-( At the low level you're just exchanging cookies. PHP provides a convenient way of allocating server-side storage for a "session" that's identified by the number in the cookie, but you could write your own system from scratch if you wanted to.

Comment: Let me know if you want a quick chat, but if you just think about it a bit, I'm sure you can work out a way to design your own persistent session system based on a cookie...